# the list is not empty but i can't use elements type ResultSet

Tags: java

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gestion_ecole","root","");
stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql="SELECT * FROM `note_mat` WHERE cin = '"+etd.cin+"'"; 
ResultSet rt=c.select(sql);
List<ResultSet> notes = new ArrayList<>();

while (rt.next())
     notes.add(rt);


 //i have problem only here the first part it's ok       
for(int i=0;i<notes.size();i++)
      System.out.println(notes.get(i).getDouble("note"));
```

// the last line generate an exception and notes.size()=5 thanks for your help

Comment: What exception is it generating?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5650)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
 at javaproject.test.main(test.java:84)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Why are you adding the `ResultSet` a bunch of times to the list. Doing `rt.next()` moves the cursor.

Comment: System.out.println(notes.get(i).getDouble("note")); //line 84

Comment: @user3144317: To improve/clarify a question, don't post comments; instead, use the "edit" link under the question.

Comment: it return more then one line

Comment: @user3144317: *"i have problem only here the first part it's ok"* No, it isn't, see Sotirios' comment above.

Comment: sorry is the firt times i use http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ResultSet` is a cursor pointing to a single row of a query returned from the database. Calling `next()` moves this cursor to the next row, and loses the previous one forever (unless you re-run the query, or scroll the `ResultSet` backwards, which is only possible in some JDBC drivers).

The main point to consider here is that `RestulSet` is a **stateful** object. There is no point in storing the same reference multiple times. Each time you call `next()`, you should extract all the useful information from the current row, and only then move on.

For example, your code snippet could be re-written to do the following:

```
List<Double> notes = new ArrayList<>();

// Save all the notes from all the rows
while (rt.next()) {
    notes.add(rt.getDouble("note"));
}

// Print all the notes
// Old-school list traversal style kept from the OP
for(int i = 0; i<notes.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(notes.get(i));
}
```

Comment: thank you but i need all the RestulSet i just tested with rt.getDouble

Comment: @user3144317 I think you've missed the point I'm trying to convey - there are no "all the ResultSet" - there is just **one**, whose state changes when you call `rt.next()`. You should extract all the data you need before moving on to the next row. E.g., you could change `note`s to be a `List<SomeClass>`, where `SomeClass` has all the fields you want to extract from the RestultSet.